# How to get wrong dll used by my application?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, dependencies, mitk

I made an exe which depend on an Open source library (of c++) MITK. Before using MITK lib I build it with Debug|32 bit configuration in visual studio. It was having no error. When I coded my project and build it with same configuration, I got following error:

> The Application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK
> to close the application

I found this [Application Failed to Initialize Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685873/application-failed-to-initialize-properly/3686443#3686443)
and as the suggestion I used ProcMon
When I looked into stack I didn't find any dll which is used from MITK lib and having any problem the stack snap shot is here

[image: Stack of my app's exe]

can any one tell me which dll is causing error?

---

Some additional info about MITK is :
It is using my systems Qt 4.8.3 library which is install by exe [means i didn't nmake it]
My other Qt applications are running properly.

Comment: could you provide a small test project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find out which dll is missing or incorrect you can take a look at [Depencencywalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see if there are any depencencies missing (make sure to get the correct version between `x32` and `x64`)