# Windows Application .Net 2.0 Error run in Windows XP SP3

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-2.0, windows-xp-sp3

I have build an application .Net 2.0 with Visual Studio 2010. 
I build in Window 7 x64.
The application contains data transaction with MySQL.Data
The solution and project build set in x86
The application running well in Win7 but when i try to run in Windows XP

The application is error the message is:
"The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000007b)."

How could i resolve that problem. Please I do need it.

Comment: Are you able to put any logging into the application to see how far it gets / what happens when it falls over?

Comment: Probably .net not installed in your XP machine

Comment: i have install all application need like .Net 2.0, Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable 2005, 2008 and 2010, and also Mysql Connector. but still not work.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685873/application-failed-to-initialize-properly) may help